# Different layout for grayscale photos

Tags: python, matplotlib, layout, grayscale

I array my photo and grayscale it but when I use different way to layout them, the grayscale photo is different.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage import data
p = "photos/1.png"
image = Image.open(p)
img_array = np.array(image)

image_gray = rgb2gray(img_array)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(image)
ax[0].set_title("Original")
ax[1].imshow(img_array)
ax[1].set_title("Array")

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
io.imshow(image_gray)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9QKb.png)

and after I use a different layout way and the grey photo looks different.

```
ax[0].imshow(image)
ax[0].set_title("Original")
ax[1].imshow(image_gray)
ax[1].set_title("Grayscale")

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

io.imshow(image_gray)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM4xI.png)

Can someone tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: You could try `imshow(image_gray, cmap='Greys')`. If the image has 3 channels (RGB), it will use those to create the colors. If, however, an image has just one channel, `imshow` applies a colormap to it. The default colormap is 'viridis' with yellow, green and blue tints.

Comment: if the first example, you're using matplotlib directly. in the second, you're using `io` (not sure what that is as its undefined). My guess is that the `io` method uses different defaults than `matplotlib`